# Is there a way to see sidequests before deploying?

Tags: armored-core-5

When selecting a mission on the world map, the only sidequest indicator I've seen is the little crown that appears when you've completed all sidequests for that mission.  One of the loading screen tips states that you can view all sidequests for a particular mission after completing said mission.

The problem is, I've found no way to view these sidequests before I actually jump into my mech and deploy to the mission.  The select button will then bring up sidequests, but several sidequests are to finish the mission in a set time frame, and viewing the sidequests does not pause time, meaning I have to do the mission at least three times:

- Initial completion.  Sidequest completion is complete luck.
- View sidequests in mission.  Will usually fail time-based sidequests.
- Run through again focusing on time-based sidequests.

Granted, this gives me a decent amount of cash to play with, but it's definitely not the most efficient way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no way.

What you could do however is deploy, quit, and then view them before actually going at it for real.

Quitting will not result in any loss.

After that, you can bring your actual runs down to two or perhaps one depending on how skilled you are.

Deploy and quit to check
Initial completion - non-time-based sidequest(s)
Second completion - timed sidequest(s)